# Full Height Angular js application scroll doesn't work on mobile

Tags: angularjs, mobile, scroll

Here is my website: [www.thebetcafe.com/app/](http://www.thebetcafe.com/app/)

I have a full height (100%) div with `overflow:auto;` or `overflow:scroll;` in an angular js application.

When trying to scroll with my finger on my mobile, The screen isn't moving and application starts to be unresponsive sometimes.

Although, it seems to work very smoothly on my pc with safari, chrome, firefox.

Any idea why?

Comment: i can scroll on my galaxy s4. what type of phone are you using?

Comment: Did you try the app page? I forgot to mention that it's thebetcafe.com/app/ that doesn't work :) I am using IOS.